# Why is a mongoose a "special needs goose"?

Tags: meaning, sean-lock

I just watched a [comedy bit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXb0X_eM4sY) by Sean Lock.

> I was at the zoo the other day and I got told off. I said, "Look! There's a mongoose!" Can't say that any more. "Special needs goose". That's what we got to say.

Why is a mongoose a "special needs goose"? This joke escapes me. Why is it funny and why is a mongoose a "special needs goose"?

Comment: I’m not at all sure if a comedy bit counts as literature. But it’s as simple as ‘Mong’ being a British-English slur for people with Down Syndrome (contraction of mongol/mongoloid) and hence for anyone stupid.

Comment: @Spagirl I actually just figured it out after quite some googling. Btw, I rest my case for posting this question on Lit.SE on this [past meta discussion](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/624/should-questions-about-speeches-by-authors-be-on-topic/629#629)

Comment: I didn’t close it so you perhaps don’t need to make a case. It just seemed like a question that may, as a straightforward vocabulary one, have fit better at ELU.

Comment: @Spagirl I agree. Or [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @North Not everything that's spoken is an [oral tradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oral_tradition).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about literature.

Comment: @EddieKal To be honest, I think referring to [speeches by authors](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/624/2191) in this context is a bit of a stretch. To the best of my knowledge (and Wikipedia's "knowledge"), Sean Lock is not an author.

Comment: @Tsundoku though the accepted answer from user111 (was that Hamlet?) specifically addresses that, saying speeches by non-authors are equally on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

It took me quite some research to connect the dots. Apparently the humor should have something to do with "mon", so I tried to draw a connection between "mon" and "special needs". But neither "Monday", "Hmong", or "mono-" makes sense in this context.

I then realized the key could be "mong" instead of "mon". [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/mong) lists it as British

> *offensive*
> A person who is stupid or who has learning difficulties.

It is a contraction of "Mongoloid". So the joke hinges on "mongoose" being taken apart as "mong" + "goose". And because of political correctness, according to the comedian Sean Lock, we are not supposed to say "mong" so we have to say "special needs goose".